# Redis pub/sub architecture returns 0 when published to chanel

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I have implemented redis based application in C#. it's a multi tier pub/sub architecture.
I have Redis desktop manager (RDM )as well as redis server running in my local.
also have a ApplicationCacheManager ACM)ication for monitoring pub/sub.
The problem is when I subscribe to a channel say

> ApplicationCacheManagerResponse

The ACM subscribes it successfully.
But when I publish to this channel with

> ApplicationCacheManagerRequest

from RDM it will return 0 and no messages are displayed in subscribed channel.

Added images for further references.

Suggest me if I am missing any steps in PUB/SUB architecture.

[image: Application Cache Manger Resp]

[image: RDM Publish command]

Answer (score 1):

0 means there's no one subscriber who received your pubilsh
https://redis.io/commands/publish

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when the PUBLISH is executed on a Slave.

Sometime during the day there was a switchover and I was executing PUBLISH on an assumed Master, but it has become a Slave and I faced this issue.